# How to center align a specific character throughout an entire page?

Tags: css, html, character, center

I'm trying to center align specific characters in a body of text for a website. I would like to only center things that have "[], *" and Roman numerals. Is there a way I can only center these without having to manually set a div tag for every single one?

Example, the "[E]" here would be centered on the page:

---

[E]

The house was red

---

Thanks! :)

Comment: What might be the reason for this? Any solution is bound to be essentially more complex than wrapping the things inside `div` elements with a class with suitable CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible since both css and html doesn't have those "if" statements, where you can tell it to do something when a condition is met.

You may use the <**center**> tag in html or **text-align:center** for css instead.

Comment: But what about with Javascript? I think I can make the function but I don't know what variable to put in order to center if the statement is true.

Comment: You haven't mentioned javascript in your question, so it likely seemd you were refering to css and html. Please clarify "what variable to put". Are you talking about the function arguments, declaring the variable that needs to be used, or variable to be used in the condition?

Comment: Sorry about that!
I mean what would I put to happen if the condition(s) have been met. For example, would I put "align=center" if the condition of "[FOOBAR]" is met?

Comment: yourdiv.setAttribute("style", "align:center;");

Comment: In the if block, which would probably be after you declared your variable,add yourvariablehere.style.textAlign = 'left'; Hope this works!